Use ssh tunnel to connect to a remote unix domain socket
To connect to a remote postgresql database I need to use an ssh tunnel. But unfortunately the remote side is configured to only accept connections on the unix domain socket. I have no authority to alter the database configuration.
The pg_hba.conf File reads as follows:
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration for IServ
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS        METHOD
# 
local   all     proftpd                 trust
local   all     all                 ident map=map1
host    all     rsyslogd        127.0.0.1/32        md5
host    all     rsyslogd        ::1/128     md5
#host   all     all     127.0.0.1/32        md5
#host   all     all     ::1/128         md5


I can connect to the remote machine via ssh and use psql client without further authentication. But I need to write a Python script using SSHTunnelForwarder or similar method.
currently I get the following error:
OperationalError: connection to server at "0.0.0.0", port 33153 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "root", database "iserv", SSL off

Is there any solution around?
EDIT
here's the Traceback containing the code-fragment, that gives the error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 9
      1 # SSH-Tunnel erstellen
      2 with SSHTunnelForwarder(
      3     (ssh_host, ssh_port),
      4     ssh_username=ssh_username,
   (...)
      7 ) as tunnel:
      8     # Verbindung zur PostgreSQL-Datenbank herstellen über den SSH-Tunnel
----> 9     conn = psycopg2.connect(
     10         host=tunnel.local_bind_host,
     11         port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
     12         database=pg_database,
     13         user=pg_user,
     14         password=None  # Da wir SSH verwenden, ist das Passwort nicht erforderlich
     15     )

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:122, in connect(dsn, connection_factory, cursor_factory, **kwargs)
    119     kwasync['async_'] = kwargs.pop('async_')
    121 dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
--> 122 conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    123 if cursor_factory is not None:
    124     conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory


EDIT
What does work is, first connecting via ssh and than opening the psql client on the client side:

establish tunnel manually

client:~/$ ssh -L 9999:/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 ******@*******.de
Linux *************.de 5.10.0-28-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.209-2 (2024-01-31) x86_64
Last login: Fri May  3 12:43:24 2024 from 91.248.125.163

server ~ # 


use psql on client side

client:~/$ psql -h localhost -p 9999 -U ****dbuser**** **database**
psql (16.0 (Debian 16.0-2), Server 13.14 (Debian 13.14-0+deb11u1))
Geben Sie »help« für Hilfe ein.

**database**=# 

Problem
I'd like to tie this together in a python script runnable (as cron job) on the client machine.

how do you get this error? Do you runs some code? Show it in question (not in comments)

What code gives this error?

There is only one sane solution: have the pg_hba.conf changed. If you don't have the authority to do that, get others to do it. Someone wants you to connect, so that someone should have the database configured accordingly. If they refuse, refuse the assignment. They might talk about Security, but hacking around a restrictive configuration is even worse security.

It is pretty easy with ssh:   ssh -L 9999:/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 192.168.0.26.  How to translate that to SSHTunnelForwarder I don't know, that is a question specifically for that module.

@LaurenzAlbe: What should I tell them to add/alter in their pg_hba.conf?
... and could you elaborate a bit more on your security argument, please?

You can add a line to allow a connection from your client machine. The connection can be encrypted if you enable ssl on the database server. That is no less secure than allowing only local connections, but building an SSL tunnel.

@LaurenzAlbe: There's a firewall inbetween that only allows me to connect via ssh on Port 22.

Firewalls can be configured.

That's not an option.
I am not in the Position to request a change in the policies.
